# Adding a listview web part - modern team sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, office-365-developer, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I need to add a list view web part with c# like below:

[image]

My best guess is using PnP is the wat to go. I would think something like below is the first part (correct me if I am wrong):

```
var page = OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.Load(ctx, "Home.aspx");
var imageWebPart = page.InstantiateDefaultWebPart(DefaultClientSideWebParts.List);
```

However I can fint anything documentation on how to set the properties as shown in the image above. All help are apreciated.

Working sample from Lee's input: 
Add following to url to get properties: ?maintenancemode=true

```
  var ctx = ClientContextExtension.GetAppContext(txtSiteUrl.Text, _configuration.AppRegistrationId, _configuration.AppRegistrationKey, new EmptyLogger());
    var page = OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.Load(ctx, "Home.aspx");

    var components = page.AvailableClientSideComponents();

    var myWebPart = components.Where(s => s.ComponentType == 1 && s.Name == "f92bf067-bc19-489e-a556-7fe95f508720").FirstOrDefault();
    if (myWebPart != null)
    {
        ClientSideWebPart ListWP = new ClientSideWebPart(myWebPart);
        ListWP.PropertiesJson = "{\"isDocumentLibrary\": true,\"showDefaultDocumentLibrary\": false,\"webpartHeightKey\": 4,\"selectedListUrl\": \"/sites/segato-slet-5000-da/Delte dokumenter\",\"listTitle\":\"Older than 30 days\",\"selectedListId\": \"2fb1f209-ea06-4a16-aed0-30980b39ccb0\",\"webRelativeListUrl\": \"/Delte dokumenter\",\"selectedViewId\":\"a20b1b00-6659-4e12-8522-609f9367631a\",\"selectedFolderPath\":\"\",\"hideCommandBar\": true}";
        var column = page.Sections[0].Columns[1];
        page.AddControl(ListWP, column);
    }
    page.Save("Home.aspx");
```

Comment: Configure a page, use Export-PnPClientSidePage to save the file as a template and examine the properties for the part. That should help on what is needed.

Comment: I found out you can add following to url and you get all properties. ?maintenancemode=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for your reference.

Use [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)

```
string _FullUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee";
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(_FullUrl))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                string password = "password";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;

                // load the page with name "page3.aspx"
                //ClientSidePage p = ClientSidePage.Load(clientContext, "ListPage.aspx");

                // get a list of possible client side web parts that can be added
                //var _components = p.AvailableClientSideComponents();

                // cc is the ClientContext instance for the site you're working with
                OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage myPage = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage(clientContext);
                myPage.PageTitle = "pageTitle";

                // get a list of possible client side web parts that can be added
                var components = myPage.AvailableClientSideComponents();

                // Find our custom "HelloWord" web part
                var myWebPart = components.Where(s => s.ComponentType == 1 && s.Name == "f92bf067-bc19-489e-a556-7fe95f508720").FirstOrDefault();
                if (myWebPart != null)
                {
                    // Instantiate a client side web part from our found web part information
                    ClientSideWebPart ListWP = new ClientSideWebPart(myWebPart);
                    ListWP.PropertiesJson = "{\"isDocumentLibrary\":false,\"selectedListId\":\"b15079b5-869b-4da8-87b6-ac0bfdf059e4\",\"listTitle\":\"MyList\",\"selectedListUrl\":\"/sites/lee/Lists/MyList\",\"webRelativeListUrl\":\"/Lists/MyList\",\"webpartHeightKey\":4}";
                    // Add the custom client side web part to the page
                    myPage.AddControl(ListWP);
                }

                // Persist the page to SharePoint
                myPage.Save("MyListWP1.aspx");
                Console.WriteLine("done");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

---

According to Lee's feedback I tried getting properties from an existing configured web part:

```
var allWebParts = page.Controls.ToList();
var webParts = page.Controls.Where(c => c.Type.Name == "ClientSideWebPart").ToList();
var listViewWebPart = webParts[3];
```

The properties for this web part:

```
Properties:
{{
  "isDocumentLibrary": true,
  "showDefaultDocumentLibrary": true,
  "webpartHeightKey": 4,
  "selectedListUrl": "",
  "listTitle": "Documents"
}}
```

PropertiesJSON:

```
"{\"isDocumentLibrary\":true,\"showDefaultDocumentLibrary\":true,\"webpartHeightKey\":4,\"selectedListUrl\":\"\",\"listTitle\":\"Documents\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks appreciated! Do you know how to set the view and the title of the web part too? How do you know what properties you can set?

Comment: Add one manually and then grab the webpart properties.  ClientSidePage p = ClientSidePage.Load(clientContext, "ListPage.aspx")  monitor p.Controls[i] properties.

Comment: I tried getting the properties but dosent provide much info: Properties:
{{
  "isDocumentLibrary": true,
  "showDefaultDocumentLibrary": true,
  "webpartHeightKey": 4,
  "selectedListUrl": "",
  "listTitle": "Documents"
}}

PropertiesJSON:
"{\"isDocumentLibrary\":true,\"showDefaultDocumentLibrary\":true,\"webpartHeightKey\":4,\"selectedListUrl\":\"\",\"listTitle\":\"Documents\"}" Are you from Microsoft Lee?

Comment: Lee what is the monitor part of your code?

Comment: Got it working. Updated post.